# Where is the Add Web Reference in VC++ 2010?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-c++

How to add a web reference to a VC++ project in Visual Studio 2010?
in VC 2010 , we don't have "Add Web Reference" Item, although we had in VC 2005.
How do I Add web reference to my VC 2010 project?
please help me.